# WebStorm 2016: How to reference "internal" jspm libraries

Tags: webstorm, aurelia, jspm

I have an Aurelia project which is divided in several projects. My folder structure looks like this

```
/myApp 
  /.idea
  /myApp
  /myModule1
  /myModule2
  /myModule3
```

Each of those is a standalone jspm package (each have their own `package.json` file). Module `myApp` refers to `myModule1`, `myModule1` and `myModule3` via `jspm install`.

in `myApp/file.js` I can do this:

```
//no file path here; this is referencing the logical name myModule1
import {Foo} from 'myModule1'
```

but a WebStorm inspector warns me that `myModule1` *is not installed*, therefore it can't give me autocomplete.

So my question is : How can I tell WebStorm about my internal libraries so that it recognizes their name and provide autocomplete?

---

Note that autocomplete works fine for all relative `import`s that use a file path (`from "./bar.js";`).

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported at this time. Please vote here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18904